# grab history command and args for different commands

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, history

I have the following exercise:

```
47  vim wilson.0321 wilson.0329
```

I need to grab the last command and args to create:

```
vim wilson.0329
```

right now I can grab the last arg or entire command:

```
intro_to_linux$ !!:$
wilson.0329

intro_to_linux$ !!
vim wilson.0321 wilson.0329
```

I'm having trouble removing `wilson.0321` from the command. anything that amounts to exactly `vim wilson.0329` from this last command words. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was the last command, this will do it:

```
!!:0 !!:2
```

If you want the last vim command you can do

```
!vim:0 !vim:2
```

Edited - had the second argument wrong in last example.

Look here for more details:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators